# Algorithm for finding the shortest cycle in a positive weighted directed graph passing through only specific nodes (not the other nodes)

Tags: algorithm, graph

A question was asked in the below link, but the answers do not mention which algorithm I can use exactly. I am wondering if the algorithm is based on Dijkstra or traveling salesman problem (TSP)
.
[Find the shortest cycle in a positive weighted directed graph passing through only specific nodes (not the other nodes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008053/find-the-shortest-cycle-in-a-positive-weighted-directed-graph-passing-through-on)

Comment: Neither.  You need a modified depth first, or breadth first, search.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Find the shortest cycle in a positive weighted directed graph passing through only specific nodes (not the other nodes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008053/find-the-shortest-cycle-in-a-positive-weighted-directed-graph-passing-through-on) If you need clarification of the answer, ask on the existing question.

Comment: "not the other nodes"  What does this mean?  That visiting the unspecified nodes is forbidden?  Or, you do not care if the unspecified nodes are visited or not?